# subir un proyecto visual studio mvc5 base de datos SQL server 2017 para dumies

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure

soy nuevo en visualstudio 
realice un proyecto en .net mvc5 con base de datos SQLserver express 2017
quiero subirlo a azure (utilizando una cuenta de estudiante)
en internet hay bastantes tutoriales pero en ellos se saltan pasos si me podrían ayudar con un tutorial para dummies

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu portal de Azure debes crear un servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seleccionas crear y estableces las propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez que lo creas revisas tu sitio en overview puedes descargar el archivo de publicacion, ese perfil de publicacion lo guardas en la carpeta de tu proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese archivo de publicacion  lo usas en tu aplicacion en tu aplicacion web tienes la opcion publicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nuevo perfil  e importar perfil alli buscas el perfil descargado.
das la opcion publicar y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te publica en la direccion de tu aplicacion web creada en azure.

Comment: listo hay todo claro y para la conexion de la base de datos  como le hago?

Comment: eso esta en tu archivo de configuracion, tienes base de datos en web, o local?

Comment: si en base de datos local. la estoy manejando en sql server 2017

Comment: El proyecto me carga a la perfeccion pero las funciones ligadas a la base de datos no funcionan (ver la listas o registrar )

Comment: en donde se encuentra tu base de datos, puedes crear una en azure y enlazarla con tu aplicacion, a veces requieres registro de cliente del lado de sql azure server.

Comment: si ya lo realice la cree en azure primero un servidor pa alojarla luego la base de datos pero al publicar nada, 
e inclusive la probe la base de datos conectandola al proyecto sin publicar y me anda normal

Comment: de la solucion que subi dale clik en que si soluciona el problema y sube tu pregunta de Base de datos como una nueva